# Remote to remote large file copy with python

Tags: python, windows, ssh, scp

I am working on someone else's Python script that transfers large files (700mb up) between two network locations. The script currently uses os.rename and shutil to copy these files. I am new to python but I understand this is copying a file from location a to my local Windows machine and then to location b. This is rather slow and I've begun looking for a way to make the copy faster, which I think will involve not copying to the local machine but directly between location a and b.

Does anyone have any insight on how to do this pythonically?

Answer (score 0):

sendfile.py = (connect\socket)

```
import os
import socket

total = []
directory = "C:\\folder\\"
files = os.listdir(directory)
for file in files:
    sock = socket.socket()
    host = "192.168.1.111"
    port = 667
    sock.connect((host, port))
    total += file.split(',')
    sock.send(str.encode(file))
    file = str.encode(directory + file)
    with open(file, "rb") as file:
        data = file.read(1024)
        resp = sock.recv(1024)
        if resp == b'Wainting file':
            file_size = os.path.getsize(arquivo)
            sock.send(bytes(str(file_size), 'utf-8'))
            if resposta == b'Waiting...':
                while data:
                    sock.send(data)
                    data = file.read(1024)
                    if not data:
                        sock.close()
                if total == files:
                    print(total)
```

revice.py = (bind/socket)

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
host = '192.168.1.111'
port = 667
sock.bind((host, port))
sock.listen(10)
total = []
while True:
    conn, addr = socket.accept()
    directory = "C:\\folder\\to_recive\\"
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    while data == b'':
        conn.close()
        conn, addr = sock.accept()
        data = conn.recv(1024)
    total += data.decode().split(',')
    name_file = total[-1]
    with open(f"{directory}{name_file}", "wb") as file:
        conn.send(b"Waiting file")
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        size = data.decode('utf-8')
        file_size = int(size)
        if file_size != 0:
            conn.send(b'Waiting...')
            print("HOST <--> " + addr[0] + f" Download {name_file} - {size} kb")
            while data:
                data = conn.recv(1024)
                file.write(data)
```